# From jQuery to flutter/dart - $.ajax

Tags: dart, flutter

im new to flutter/dart and was wondering how to convert this js to flutter/dart ?

I have looked at lots of flutter/dart tutorials, but all are just how to render stuff using widgets, i have not found any tutorial on how "base" classes work.

```js
 function callAjax(method, url, params, callback) {
  var asynchronously = true;
  if(callback === undefined) {
   asynchronously = false;
  }
  if(params === undefined) {
   params = '';
  }
  
  var ajaxUrl = url;
  ajaxUrl = ajaxUrl.toLowerCase() + params;
  
  var result = null;
  
  $.ajax(ajaxUrl, {
   processData: false,
   async: asynchronously,
   data: {},
   type: method,
   contentType: 'application/json',

   success:function(jsondata){
    if(asynchronously) { 
     callback(jsondata); 
    } else {
     result = jsondata;
    }
   },
    
   error:function(xhr, status, error){
    alert('Internal Server Error: ' + xhr.status + ' (' + url + params + ')');
    if(asynchronously) { callback(null); }
   },
  }); 
  
  if(!asynchronously) { return result; }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Got as far as this ..

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class CallAjax {
  String method;
  String url;
  String params;
  Function callback;

  CallAjax(this.method, this.url, this.params, this.callback);
  
}
```

Comment: https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/

Comment: I saw that, dose not say how to set async true/false

Comment: HTTP Requests should only be async.

Comment: That's really helpful :P

Answer (score 4):

Think i got it now :)
Posting code in case anyone else needs it.

```js
Future<void> fetchHttpGet(String url, String params, Function callback) async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.encodeFull(url + params),
    headers: {
      'Content-type' : 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
  );

  if(response == null || response.statusCode != 200) {
    callback(null);
  } else {
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    callback(responseJson);
  }
}
```